# Mocha и Sinon. Как сделать идемпотентные тесты, без памяти состояния?

Tags: javascript, юнит-тесты, mocha

Имею папку `tests`, в которой лежит чуть более 10 файлов с тестами.

Запускаю файлы по отдельности - **все работает.**

Когда запускаю как `mocha *` или `mocha file1.js file2.js` получаю ошибку.

**Ошибка связана с тем**, что у меня один экземпляр `сервиса для базы данных`, на который я ставлю `заглушки`.

Пример:

File1:

```
sinon.stub(database.__proto__, "findAll").returns(1);
```

File2:

```
sinon.stub(database.__proto__, "findAll").returns(2);
```

Как сделать их идемпотентными? Убрать эту "память" между тестами.

Comment: https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/#stubreset
Но вообще непонятно зачем ставить заглушки на `__proto__`?

Comment: Заглушки ставлю чтобы не поднимать базу данных для unit тестов.

Comment: Это понятно. Непонятно зачем на `database.__proto__`, а не просто на `database`

Comment: `database` - экземпляр класса `Database`. По другому у меня не работало. Пишу "одиночкой".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил используя флаг `mocha` [--parallel](https://mochajs.org/#parallel-tests)